# Creation age of a post

Tags: feature-request

I (and anyone) can see when a post was "handled" last (edited, answered,...) but I'd prefer to also see when it was first created. (Obviously, I can do that by simply opening the post, but then it is already too late, you little exhumated attention-stealing post, you :-) Even Windows (gasp) has a "Created" attribute that could be shown in the files viewer (and be used for sorting), on Reddit I always sort by date - is there a possibility to do this on SE too? (I'm not that long or frequently here, and didn't check all features yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [homepage](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) sorts on activity ("last handling") by default, but the [list of questions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/) has the option to [sort on newest questions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest) as well, and it shows the "created" attribute you're looking for ... but only for questions, not answers.

As you noticed, you have to go to the Q&A page itself to see when the question and answers were created. There's no option to change this; one of the reasons is that the list pages are cached and shown the same way for everybody. Therefore, they are not customizable.

Comment: Ah, I see now that homepage!=list of questions - I always thought I already was on the question page...

Comment: An additional problem is that the web page for a question and its answers doesn't show the creation date of community wiki question or answers.